# What is the N on a product mean?

Tags: variance, mean, descriptive-statistics, standard-error, ecology

I want to sum the means of various measures within a treatment group, and found previous posts helpfully describing how to calculate the [Standard error of estimated sum or product mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498224/standard-error-of-estimated-sum-or-product-mean#new-answer?newreg=8d64cecae7424de9811fb4462a1f92f7). My question is, can I estimate a number of observations (N) for these derived statistics?

As an example, let's say I measured 5 amino acid concentrations, but the number of valid observations for each amino acid varies. Here are the summary stats:

|  | ala | gly | val | leu | pro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **mean conc** | 3.5 | 3.0 | 2.8 | 1.1 | 0.4 |
| **std dev** | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.1 |
| **N** | 10 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 9 |

I want to estimate a mean total amino acid concentration, and its SE. The first part is easy; I can easily add the means to find the average total amino acid concentration.

$$
3.5 + 3.0 + 2.8 + 1.1 + 0.4 = 10.8
$$

Then I estimate the SE of the summed means as the square root of the sum of the N-adjusted squares of the standard deviations, expressed in general as:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{stdev_a^2}{N_a}+\frac{stdev_b^2}{N_b}+\frac{stdev_c^2}{N_c}+...}
$$

or here as:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{0.3^2}{10}+\frac{0.7^2}{5}+\frac{0.5^2}{6}+\frac{0.6^2}{2}+\frac{0.1^2}{9}} =  0.574
$$
*or sqrt(((0.3^2)/10)+((0.7^2)/5)+((0.5^2)/6)+((0.6^2)/2)+((0.1^2)/9)) if you want to paste it into your program of choice*

Now: **can I estimate an effective N for this statistic?** If there is a valid way to estimate such a thing, what is the approach? Surely it is not the sum of Ns, as that would be very high (32 observations). I have a random hunch that it could be the square root of the sum of Ns, which would be 5.65. This makes intuitive sense to me, and is also not too far from the mean (6.4) or median (6). However, my statistics training is woefully inadequate and I have no idea even how to search for the answer to this question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

*P.S. This is my first post, I would be glad for suggested edits to improve its clarity and usefulness. Thanks!!*

Comment: Welcome to CV, Amanda.  Are you making a distinction between "stdev" and "SE"?  (You should, but it's not clear that you are.)  What would an "effective N" mean?  How would you use it?  Do you even need it?

Comment: Yes, stdev = standard deviation = SD ; SE = standard error = SEM = SD/sqrt(N). I presented SDs in the table to enable the summed SE calculation, but ultimately I am looking for a table with means, SEs, and Ns.

I think I need an N on my summed means so I can perform ANOVA on the "total amino acid concentration" values, as in the ind.oneway.second from (archived) R package rpsychi https://github.com/cran/rpsychi/blob/master/R/ind.oneway.second.R

Comment: This a weird workaround to the fact that I have so many holes in my data. For instance, in my example above, 8 of my 10 samples don't have values for leu, which would reduce each sample's total amino acid concentration by ~1 which is substantial. Other alternatives I have considered but don't love are: a) fill in holes by imputing values; b) fill holes with mean or median values. I am very open to other suggestions!

Comment: *Edit: I do need SDs (not SEs) for that R function, but I'd like to publish SEs in the table I present in a final manuscript.

Comment: If you need to do an ANOVA, why not perform it on the original data rather than the summarized data?

Comment: I believe all 5 amino acids (ala, gly, val, leu, pro) are present in every sample, but for many samples I could only measure a subset of these individual amino acids. Say for example I can measure ala+gly+val in one sample, but gly+leu+pro in another, and ala+val+leu+pro in a third. (The method involves isotope tracers and is complicated to describe succinctly, but I have reason to believe I can obtain data on each individual amino acid independently, so an invalid measurement on ala does not invalidate a gly measurement and vice versa. Nor do I believe an invalid measurement = a true zero.)

Comment: Thus if I calculate "total amino acids" within each sample, they vary greatly due to the absence of data for entire amino acids. ANOVA on these data won't reflect variability due to treatment, but rather variability due to methodological issues. If I can average each amino acid individually across all the samples in a treatment group, PRIOR to taking the sum, I believe I will get a more reasonable estimate of the "total amino acids" in that group. This leaves me with only summarized data with which to try to perform ANOVA or similar tests.

Comment: If I had better data I could drop incomplete cases and proceed with ANOVA on the original data; but most of these data are incomplete cases... As I said above, I have considered imputing values to complete cases, but am wary of this approach.